# Copy same select mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```sql
        SELECT 
             concat(b.Name, " -FirstName") as Name                
        FROM table b
        UNION 
        SELECT 
             concat(b.Name, " -SecondName") as Name                
        FROM table b
```

The result is :

> Frank -FirstName, Frank -SecondName

This works fine, but i think that could exist another way to do this without `union`.

**Edit**: I need two rows with different results from same field value.

```
Row1 = Frank -FirstName
Row2 = Frank -SecondName
```

**Edit2**: I can't change the BD too much. I will work with a unique row. Thanks to all!

Comment: What exactly output required for example?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam `Frank -FirstName, Frank -SecondName`

Comment: Its non-sense, no one need repeatition

Comment: I need two rows with diferent results.

Comment: thats wrong as in same row

Comment: yes.. i see the edited post just now. i deleted my answer

Comment: @Jm.ortega Hope you don't mind, but why do you need the same field (name) as firstname and second name each? (though thinking about possibilities I couldn't think about any probable use cases for such a usage)

Comment: I think you should focus more on database design than trying to work with this. Possible, yes. Worth it, probably not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL split values to multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam not sure one can see it as a duplicate of that. The one question has multiple values in one field. Here he wants to duplicate each and every line. So even though the current question here does not make much sense to me I don't see there anything in the direction of duplicitism.

Comment: Even if there's a good reason to repeat data like this, why would you want to do it without `UNION`? Why make it complicated?